# Where can I find a list of English words that contain a rare combination of phonemes

Tags: english, reference-request, phonemes, words

I am looking for a wake up word for a digital product that would be easily detected with a voice recognition engine.

This calls for a word that has a rare combination of phonemes so the product is not accidentally activated. At the same time it has to be a good name for the product and it has to a word in proper English.

For example, the word "orange" has a rare combination of phonemes in English, so what I am looking for is a list of such words.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a list of rare combinations, you can search [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse#page/n5/mode/2up) for them. Otherwise you'll have to generate one.